# htmlのフォームの要素を上手い具合に配列にして使いたい

Tags: html, json

以下のようなhtmlを用意しました。

```
<form>
  <h2>クエリ１</h2>
  <input type="hidden" name="query[][name]" value="query1">
  <input type="hidden" name="query[][params][][name]" value="param11">
  パラメータ１<input type="text" name="query[][params][][value]" value="value11"><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="query[][params][][name]" value="param12">
  パラメータ２<input type="text" name="query[][params][][value]" value="value12"><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="query[][params][][name]" value="param13">
  パラメータ３<input type="text" name="query[][params][][value]" value="value13"><br>

  <h2>クエリ２</h2>
  <input type="hidden" name="query[][name]" value="query2">
  <input type="hidden" name="query[][params][][name]" value="param21">
  パラメータ１<input type="text" name="query[][params][][value]" value="value21"><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="query[][params][][name]" value="param22">
  パラメータ２<input type="text" name="query[][params][][value]" value="value22"><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="query[][params][][name]" value="param23">
  パラメータ３<input type="text" name="query[][params][][value]" value="value23"><br>

  <input type="submit" value="送信">
</form>
```

このフォームの送信ボタンを押した際、送られるデータをjson形式で見た場合に以下のようになると予想しました。

```
{
  "query": [
    {
      "name": "query1",
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "param11",
          "value": "value11"
        },
        {
          "name": "param12",
          "value": "value12"
        },
        {
          "name": "param13",
          "value": "value13"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "query2",
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "param21",
          "value": "value21"
        },
        {
          "name": "param22",
          "value": "value22"
        },
        {
          "name": "param23",
          "value": "value23"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

しかし結果は次のようになり、ぐちゃぐちゃでした。

```
{
  "query": [
    {
      "params": [
        { "value": "value11" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "params": [
        { "value": "value12" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "params": [
        { "value": "value13" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "params": [
        { "value": "value21" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "params": [
        { "value": "value22" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "params": [
        { "value": "value23" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "params": [
        { "name": "param11" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "params": [
        { "name": "param12" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "params": [
        { "name": "param13" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "params": [
        { "name": "param21" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "params": [
        { "name": "param22" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "query1",
      "params": [
        { "name": "param23" }
      ]
    },
    { "name": "query2" }
  ]
}
```

htmlの`name`属性をどのように書けば、予想のような形になるでしょうか？
ちなみに配列の部分を、

```
{
  "0": {
    ...
  },
  "1": {
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

といった書き方はしたくありません。連想配列ではなく普通の配列の形にして使いたいです。

Comment: 「したくありません」とは書いてあるもののインデックスを指定しないのでいけないのではないかと。`[]`を使った場合、1要素の下にまとめて配列を入れられないので、配下の要素は別々の要素になってしまいます。"したくない"理由や、変換する手間はあるとおもいますが……。

Comment: つまりparamsの部分を配列にしても、"name"と"value"を同時に持ったオブジェクトを追加するのは出来ないのですね……。たしかに最初の書き方だと"name"のみを持ったオブジェクトと"value"のみをもったオブジェクトを追加するような書き方ですしね(それすら叶いませんでしたが……)

Answer (score 1):

インデックス番号を指定してあげないと、同じ連想配列に含めたいという意図が伝わらないのではないでしょうか。

```
<form>
  <h2>クエリ１</h2>
  <input type="hidden" name="query[0][name]" value="query1">
  <input type="hidden" name="query[0][params][0][name]" value="param11">
  パラメータ１<input type="text" name="query[0][params][0][value]" value="value11"><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="query[0][params][1][name]" value="param12">
  パラメータ２<input type="text" name="query[0][params][1][value]" value="value12"><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="query[0][params][2][name]" value="param13">
  パラメータ３<input type="text" name="query[0][params][2][value]" value="value13"><br>

  <h2>クエリ２</h2>
  <input type="hidden" name="query[1][name]" value="query2">
  <input type="hidden" name="query[1][params][0][name]" value="param21">
  パラメータ１<input type="text" name="query[1][params][0][value]" value="value21"><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="query[1][params][1][name]" value="param22">
  パラメータ２<input type="text" name="query[1][params][1][value]" value="value22"><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="query[1][params][2][name]" value="param23">
  パラメータ３<input type="text" name="query[1][params][2][value]" value="value23"><br>

  <input type="submit" value="送信">
</form>
```